# WPF Validation for TextBlock

Tags: wpf, xaml

Just Making a WPF Desktop Application.
I am Using various validations.
In TextBox if I am using ,
NotifyOnValidationError=True,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,ValidatesOnExceptions=True
Its working fine.But in TextBlock if I am using the same thing the whole block is highlighted with red sign .... i just want an excla. (!) mark ..`NotifyOnValidationError=True,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,ValidatesOnExceptions=True`. what should i do ?

Comment: Did you get a chance to try my suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override the default error template defined in the Validation class you can simply define a ControlTemplate and assign that to the TextBlock `Validation.ErrorTemplate` attached property.

```
<TextBlock
Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource TextBlockErrorTemplate}">     
<TextBlock>
```

Within a Resource dictionary you can define an error template like so:

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBlockErrorTemplate">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                           Foreground="Red"
                           FontSize="14pt"
                           Margin="-15,0,0,0"
                           FontWeight="Bold">!
                </TextBlock>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="controlWithError" />
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
```